# Add Custom Files to a Package to be installed on specific paths with productbuild/pkgbuild?

Tags: macos, terminal, install, mobile-device-management

I build my pkg with productbuild and pkgbuild.

My root path looks like this: ROOT > Applications/Scripts/Library/private/

In Applications/ is my .app , which works. However in Library for example is another folder "Desktop Pictures" and there is a background.png. I would like to have that exact path with the .png on the device that i install this package, so i can use it later for automatically set the background.

Not working tho

This is how the pkg gets build:

```
pkgbuild --root "ROOT" \
--identifier "${IDENTIFIER}" \
--version "${VERSION}" \
--install-location "/" \
--sign "${IDENTITY}" \
--scripts ROOT/Scripts \
"${PACKAGE_NAME}_before.pkg"


productbuild \
--distribution distribution.dist \
--scripts "ROOT/Scripts" \
--sign "${IDENTITY}" \
--package-path "${PACKAGE_NAME}_before.pkg" \
"${PACKAGE_NAME}.pkg"
```

Edit:
Although the command

```
pkgutil --payload-files mypackage.pkg
```

Tells me for example:

```
.
./Library
./Library/Desktop Pictures
./Library/Desktop Pictures/background.png
```

Edit: I basically found out, that manually installing the pkg and typing in my password, its working.

So let me rephrase my question:
How is it possible to install the files to my mac without having access to password input, since its automated?